# Facebook Graph API has changed their date string format into a 6 digit year format? Cannot parse date

Tags: javascript, facebook, datetime, facebook-graph-api, datetime-format

I have an app using Facebook Graph API sending a GET request to a facebook group feed like so `GET/v2.7/142679255268/feed`. The GET request is receiving back a weird date string with 6 digits where the year should be. This is what the weird datetime format looks like:

```
// Weird date string format corresponds to September 14 at 6:22pm
updated_time: 469164-06-03T19:09:24+0000
```

Previously the date format returned was:

```
// Previous date string format corresponds as expected to May 14th 
updated_time: 2016-05-14T03:54:42+0000
```

It's not just my app that is getting this weird date string format. Check out the official Graph API Explorer for /group/feed and the [same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYhXT.png) is returned :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=142679255268%2Ffeed&version=v2.7

Anyone know wtf is this date string format format and how to convert it to ISO8601? Thanks!

// ======================================================================

Alternatively, does anyone know how to specify post fields to retrieve in my query? Instead of `updated_time`, I want to get the `created_at` field for each post coming from the groupfeed.

```
// The standard GET
GET/v2.7/142679255268/feed
// GET with limit of 10 posts
GET/v2.7/142679255268/feed?limit=10

// Now how to specify desired attributes of the fb posts coming from the feed?
```

Comment: That doesn’t look like a deliberate change, but rather like a bug. Suggest you go file a report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: _“does anyone know how to specify post fields to retrieve in my query?”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields

Comment: Bug reported! Thanks @CBroe, I wasn't sure if it was a bug or not. Hopefully Facebook will fix it soon!